# Sending Automatic email in PHP?

Tags: php, email, cron

I have created a registration and after successful registration user get a email about login details(this happens when user clicks submit button).But i have stuck with a sending another email automatically to the same user after 5 minutes and after 20 days user have registered.in the mysql database registration time saved as Time_created.(timestamp).[2016-04-26 10:25:30].what is the possible way to do this.

Here is my code to send email from form this works correctly.

```
$r = $_GET['rid'];
    $aaaa= mysql_query("SELECT email FROM gotest WHERE ID= '$r'");
    $bbbb = mysql_fetch_array($aaaa);
    $email = $bbbb['email'];


    $to      = $email;

    $subject = ' Site| login '; 
    $message = '

        Thanks for signing up!
        Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials.

        ------------------------
        Username: '.$name.'
        Password: '.$pass.'


        ------------------------ ';


    $headers .= 'From:noreply@xxx.net' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc:zzz@xxx.net' ."\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You would have to set up a CRON job that will run every 5 minutes and check the database for users registered in the last couple of minutes. Do the same thing for 20 days.

Comment: @bub no i mean i wnat to send a another email to the same user with different content after 5 minutes

Comment: @MarioPlantosar any example please?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of registration, add `mail send date` & `set no_of_email_send=1`. Set a cron which will check whether `mail_send_date + 5 mints > now()` & no_of_email_send == 1.If this condition satisfy, then send 2nd email & update `mail send date & set no_of_email_send=2`. If  `no_of_email_send == 2` then `check mail send date + 20days > now()` then send 3rd email & update mail send date & `set no_of_email_send=3` You can do the validation using single query also.

Comment: iam not familiar with Cron.can you express me using my code how to do it.it will be really appreciate

Comment: cron is the time-based job scheduler. cron enables users to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at certain times or dates. It is commonly used to automate system maintenance or administration.   search in google "how to set cron" (as per your OS) or follow the link: http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml  http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: no need for that additional field "no_of_email_send(t)" in the table. You can use mysql query like this instead "SELECT id FROM users WHERE time_created >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND time_created < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);"

Comment: It is your logic, I have suggested only the approach